# Display dual variable with Pulp

Tags: pulp

I try to display dual variable using pulp with default solver, but I always obtain "None" for the dual values.

For this example :

```
from pulp import *
prob = LpProblem("test080", LpMinimize)
x = LpVariable("x", 0, 5)
y = LpVariable("y", -1, 1)
z = LpVariable("z", 0)
c1 = x+y <= 5
c2 = x+z >= 10
c3 = -y+z == 7

prob += x + 4*y + 9*z, "obj"
prob += c1, "c1"
prob += c2,"c2"
prob += c3,"c3"

prob.solve()
```

If I print the dual value of each of the constraints using .pi I obtain "None".

Is there a way to obtain the dual value using the default solver of pulp?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the LP information from the default solver (CBC), you have to explicitly tell the solver the problem is an LP:

```py
prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(mip=False))
print(c3.pi)
# 8.0
```